# How to set the Tab Index or current Active control from code in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have tried following method, but it didn't work at all, current focus stays on the very first textbox to whom i have set as TabIndex 0 through UI :-

```
private void OnFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtServername.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.LastServerName;
            txtDatabase.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.LastDatabase;
            txtUsername.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.LastUserName;
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtServername.Text))
                txtDatabase.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, false, true, true, true);
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDatabase.Text))
                txtUsername.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, false, true, true, true);
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUsername.Text))
                txtPassword.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, false, true, true, true);
        }
```

Could someone please suggest a solution to above problem?

Comment: I think you can use foucs method of textbox

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam Tried!!! that doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method

```
textBox.Select();
```

Tested at my side, so i think it should work

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam, sorry for the duplicate answer. I didn't read the answers before I posted mine. Anyways, textBox.Focus(); also works on default WinForm controls.